# How to grep whole numbers including special characters?

Tags: grep

I have a file called test with the below lines:

```
1. Lil Nas X Ft, Billy Ray Cyrus - Old Town Road (Remix).mp3
10. Mark Ronson - Find U Again (feat. Camila Cabello).mp3
11.  Mabel  -  Mad Love.mp3
12. Sigala & Becky Hill - Wish You Well.mp3
13. CamelPhat & Jake Bugg - Be Someone.mp3
14. Jess Glynne & Jax Jones - One Touch.mp3
15. Zara Larsson - Don't Worry Bout Me.mp3
16. Pink Ft, Cash Cash - Can We Pretend.mp3
17.  Jax Jones & Martin Solveig & Madison Beer  -  All Day And Night (Jax Jones & Martin Solveig Present Europa).mp3
18. Martin Garrix - Summer Days (feat. Macklemore & Patrick Stump of Fall Out Boy).mp3
19. Little Mix - Bounce Back.mp3
```

I want grep for the 1st column using 1. representing the song name. Command I am using is:

```
#cat test | grep -w "1."

1. Lil Nas X Ft, Billy Ray Cyrus - Old Town Road (Remix).mp3
10. Mark Ronson - Find U Again (feat. Camila Cabello).mp3
11.  Mabel  -  Mad Love.mp3
12. Sigala & Becky Hill - Wish You Well.mp3
13. CamelPhat & Jake Bugg - Be Someone.mp3
14. Jess Glynne & Jax Jones - One Touch.mp3
15. Zara Larsson - Don't Worry Bout Me.mp3
16. Pink Ft, Cash Cash - Can We Pretend.mp3
17.  Jax Jones & Martin Solveig & Madison Beer  -  All Day And Night (Jax Jones & Martin Solveig Present Europa).mp3
18. Martin Garrix - Summer Days (feat. Macklemore & Patrick Stump of Fall Out Boy).mp3
19. Little Mix - Bounce Back.mp3
```

Everything seems to be grepped for. But I am supposing to only see the below:

```
1. Lil Nas X Ft, Billy Ray Cyrus - Old Town Road (Remix).mp3
```

Comment: I wonder why you included the AIX tag along with the Linux tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even as a fixed string, `1.` would match `11.`. But it's not a string, it's a regular expression, so certain characters apply rules rather than matching literals.

The dot is a stand-in for "*any character*"; to match a literal dot you need to escape it as `\.`. You could also include a marker for start-of-line (a caret, `^`), so that the `1.` will only match at the beginning of the line.

You can also discard the `cat` because `grep` (and many other commands) accept a filename directly.

You then get something like this

```
grep '^1\.' test
```

which in your dataset matches just the one line

```
1. Lil Nas X Ft, Billy Ray Cyrus - Old Town Road (Remix).mp3
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for me :)